# Download a file from a S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, https

I have a file stored on a S3 bucket that I want to download. It's possible to download that file using HTTP on a S3 in a secure way? Normally we do it by https. I also saw that we can use ftp server for the download, but I don't know if I want to go on that way. Any tip?

Comment: http = insecure

Comment: The answer is to use HTTPS.